# Reparse points, placeholders, sizes in parentheses, and Dropbox SmartSync

Tags: dropbox, reparse-points, placeholder

I use OneDrive, where each file in the relevant Windows folder is a reparse point (visible through dir /al). When I clear the Windows space for a particular file, it becomes a placeholder with the size shown in parentheses on the relevant dir output; while (obviously) remaining a reparse point. When I use the file, it comes back to disk, the parentheses disappear, but it remains a reparse point. This makes sense.

I also have an extensive Dropbox folder using SmartSync.

When a SmartSync'd file is in online only state, it is visible as a reparse point, with the files showing as placeholders with size in parentheses, and the space definitely not occupied.

When it is in local state, it is no longer a reparse point, and the file is not a placeholder.

So far so good.

However, if I *use* an online only file, it seems to end up in a halfway house state where it no longer shows as a reparse point; it is definitely available on disk (using space); but it still shows as a placeholder with size in parentheses.

Even worse, if I robocopy an online only file, it loses its reparse point status (because it's been used), stays a placeholder with parentheses, and lands up on the target with all its data, but marked as a placeholder with parentheses there as well (making it look worryingly as if the target might still be dependent on Dropbox for its data - though it clearly isn't, and the target file is anyway not a reparse point).

Does anyone have any explanation of all this strange Dropbox placeholder behaviour? I can't find any discussion of it on the web (though I may have missed something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dir` shows parentheses when the file has the 'Offline' attribute ([FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants)). However, that does not indicate that the file is actually a "placeholder" of any sort – it just means Dropbox forgot to unset the attribute.

It was unexpected to me, but it seems that 'Offline' can be arbitrarily set/unset on any file (even if there's no corresponding mechanism to actually *make* it offline) and you can even do so through the `attrib` program:

```
C:\> echo Test! > foo.txt
C:\> attrib +o foo.txt
C:\> dir foo.txt
       (7) foo.txt
```

Actually it might be intentional on Dropbox's part – notice that if the *parent folder* is changed to "Local" via Smart Sync, then Dropbox removes the 'Offline' attribute from all files as well. However, if the folder is set to "Online-only" via Smart Sync, then even downloaded files retain the 'Offline' attribute, which is perhaps supposed to mean that they're considered "temporarily cached" and Dropbox **may** convert them back into online-only when disk space is low.

> [image: Screenshot of Dropbox's "Automatically make files online-only" feature]

---

Use `fsutil reparsepoint query` to see the "reparse tag" contents of a reparse point.

Use `fsutil file layout` to examine an NTFS file's structure. If it actually holds data, then the `::$DATA` stream will show up as having the correct allocated size.

(Ignore the presence of ":com.dropbox.attrs:$DATA"; that's an ordinary Alternate Data Stream – an xattr – which is passive and doesn't influence filesystem behavior.)

Comment: Brilliant thanks, that's exactly what I needed, especially attrib -o, which I would not have had the nerve to use without your explanation even if I'd spotted it!

Comment: Also just realised that dir /ao works, to show offline files only, completing the picture.